Google Sheets: Clone current sheet document to a new document ("Make a copy") from script
Is it possible to make a script that will, so to say, "save as" the current sheet to a new name, making a copy, that can then be immediately opened in a new tab? The programmatic equivalent of File->Make a copy.

Combining things from a bunch of different sources, and using @Kreeszh's answer as a starting point, I have arrived at the following. Firstly, a utility function which allows the fully-automated opening of a new tab from a script:
function OpenURL(url)
{
  var html =
  '<html>'
  + '<script>'
  +   'window.close = function()'
  +     '{'
  +       'window.setTimeout('
  +         'function()'
  +         '{'
  +           'google.script.host.close();'
  +         '}, 10);'
  +     '};'
  +   'var result = window.open("' + url + '");'
  +   'if (result)'
  +     'close();'
  + '</script>'
  // Offer URL as clickable link in case above code fails.
  + '<body style="word-break: break-word; font-family:sans-serif;">'
  +   'Failed to open automatically. '
  +   '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank" onclick="window.close()">Click here to proceed</a>.'
  + '</body>'
  + '<script>'
  +   'google.script.host.setHeight(40);'
  +   'google.script.host.setWidth(410);'
  + '</script>' +
  '</html>';

  var htmlOutputObject = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(90).setHeight(1);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutputObject, "Opening...");
}

Caveat: In order for this to work, the browser must not be blocking popups. In Firefox, this is configured by going to the hamburger -> Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Permissions -> Block pop-up windows -> Exceptions. By adding an exception for "https://docs.google.com", popups can be permitted from arbitrary code running in the context of a Google Docs document.
This function is adapted from answers to this question:
Google Apps Script to open a URL
Then, armed with this function, I was able to write the following function (with bespoke functionality) to start a new document by cloning the current one:
function StartNewInvoice()
{
  var invoicesFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("188RjmsuYas0YFg0OOUSlXzfQzePQmMzM");

  var lastInvoiceNumber = -1;
  var invoiceCreatorFile = null;

  var allFiles = invoicesFolder.getFiles();

  while (allFiles.hasNext())
  {
    var file = allFiles.next();

    var fileName = file.getName();

    if (fileName.startsWith("Invoice #"))
    {
      var invoiceNumber = parseInt(fileName.substring(9));

      if (invoiceNumber > lastInvoiceNumber)
        lastInvoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }
    else if (fileName == "Invoice Creator")
      invoiceCreatorFile = file;
  }

  var newInvoiceNumber = lastInvoiceNumber + 1;

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  spreadsheet.getRange("F13").setValue(newInvoiceNumber);
  spreadsheet.getRange("F16").setValue(new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10));

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  var newInvoiceFileName = "Invoice #" + newInvoiceNumber;

  var newInvoice = invoiceCreatorFile.makeCopy(newInvoiceFileName, invoicesFolder);

  var newInvoiceURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + newInvoice.getId();

  OpenURL(newInvoiceURL);

  spreadsheet.getRange("F13").setValue(1);
}


You can definitely generate a copy, store it in a defined folder, and display a link that when clicked will open in a new window.
function copyWorkbook() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var name = spreadsheet.getName();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
  var todaysDate = new Date().toLocaleString();
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("destination_folder_sheet_ID"); 
  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).makeCopy(name + ' ' + todaysDate, destFolder); 
  var copyId = copyFile.getId();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var url = `<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${copyId}/" target="_blank">${name}</a>`;
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(url);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "testing");
}


Nice, thanks! This certainly gives me something to start playing with.

No problem! Consider an upvote or an accepted answer to help me get out of stack overflow reputation jail. If the auto-open in new window feature is make or break, I tested out @Saddles recommendation and it works perfectly but it looks like they left out  in the empty quotes at the end.

I have found a fully-automated solution, which I arrived at starting from your answer. I will post my solution as a separate answer but mark your answer as the accepted one. :-)

Here's my complete solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78640162/166815

ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION
This sample script uses a custom menu and a modal dialog to "save as" the current sheet to a new name, making a copy, that can then be immediately opened in a new tab.
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('My Function', 'myFunction')
    .addToUi();
}

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets();
  var n = SpreadsheetApp.create(`${ss.getName()}: ${new Date().toDateString()}`);

  sh.forEach(sheet => {
    var dt = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var ns = n.getSheetByName(sheet.getName());
    if (!ns) {
      ns = n.insertSheet(sheet.getName());
    }
    ns.getRange(1, 1, dt.length, dt[0].length).setValues(dt);
  })

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<script>" + "window.open('" + n.getUrl() + "');" + "google.script.host.close();" + "</script>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, "Opening a new tab...");
}

The sample sheet looks like this:

OUTPUT

REFERENCES

Custom Menus in Google Workspace

Class HtmlService



I keep getting Image uploads are limited to 50 megapixels; please use a smaller image, which is why I'm unable to provide a GIF output showing that it can be immediately opened in a new tab.

Awesome, thanks so much :-) Does this preserve formatting?

It doesn't since the script is using getValues() and setValues(), which is a limitation in the methods. I believe @Kreeszh's answer addresses that with makeCopy(). I'll just update the answer since it didn't seem to copy over the script tags when I pasted the script.
